# What are the application areas of Pattern formation studies specific to biology?

Tags: mathematical-models, development

I was reading about reaction-diffusion processes, morphogenesis concept by Alan Turing and works of Murray in describing pattern formation on animals etc. But one question which came to my mind was even if we describe these processes in mathematical and physical contexts, are there any application areas awaiting for the results?

Comment: What do you mean "awaiting for the results?" Do you mean, are there unsolved problems in pattern formation that would have implications for biology, if the answer was known?

Comment: Yes. Specifically can such advancements help in any area like repairing an organ or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm not quite sure if we are at the repairing an organ phase, but here are a few interesting examples: 
1. Philip Maini at Oxford has used pattern formation to give insight into jaguar patterning: [Paper](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/maini/PKM%20publications/212.pdf). He also has a book chapter [Pattern formation and wound healing](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/maini/PKM%20publications/119.pdf) that could of of interest, although I'm not sure if this is a direct application as much as a heuristic understanding of how wound healing happens.

2. From the biomedical side, Michael Levin at Tufts is doing amazing work in regenerative medicine, and a lot of what he does is inspired by pattern formation as well, although I am not sure if it explicitly uses the theory - [his papers](http://ase.tufts.edu/biology/labs/levin/publications/).
3. [This paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v434/n7037/abs/nature03461.html) is one of my favorite from Ron Weiss - engineered pattern formation. Will most likely have important biomedical applications some day, although not currently.

Comment: It is quite interesting to know this. Tissue engineering, biomaterial fabrication and
biosensing.